# Blender rigid body ignoring the curve modifier

Tags: physics

I'm trying to set up a conveyor belt system in Blender. I have something I think should be working, using an animation bound to a path with the curve modifier.

However, the when the sim starts it's as if Blender ignores the fact the curve modifier is there. I've got the deform box checked in the rigid body properties for the geo and it does nothing. I've also tried it with it set to final and no luck.

I've also tried the file in three separate versions of blender with no luck. Anyone know whats up?

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1plNG8A114pnjT4mTtsO-c1Y3rjVXroN_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the hair pulling exercises of arcane 3d animation, Billy!

While your "Cube.003" was increasing in X direction during animation, and it was Curved to wrap around the BeltCurve, the Active Cube was not seeing it as wrapped, so it just kept riding along.

I noticed that you did not have Curve Path Animated....

[image]

As the conveyor was also moving in the opposite direction, I deduced that the Curve was formed in the wrong direction, so I rotated it 180 Deg around the X axis.

But I'm not sure what the root cause of the problem was.  Perhaps you can compare my recreated solution.

Here is my example: [image]

[image]